# Delete ParseObject matching Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to delete a ParseObject matching a certain query. Presently im first retrieving the object using a query, and then deleting it in the done() method. This seems like a waste of network call. Is there a way of doing this in a single call without retrieving the object?

```
        String currentUsername = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();
        String friendUsername  = friendList.get(userPosition).getUsername();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserFriends");
        pQuery.whereEqualTo("username"  , friendUsername);
        pQuery.whereEqualTo("Fusername" , currentUsername); 
        pQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 
        {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) 
            {
                if(object!=null)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Object not null");
                    object.deleteEventually();
                }else
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error Deleting");
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error Deleting:"+Integer.toString(e.getCode()));
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error Deleting:"+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: deleting from network call again?

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand.

Comment: for deleting r u hitting http query?

Comment: Im using the Parse SDK. So im doing it in `object.deleteEventually();`

Comment: did you retrieved that object before?

Comment: @NaveedAli Nop. Querying it for the first time. Im familiar with `createWithoutData` but cant user that here since I dont have the `objectId`

Comment: I think you can not delete it unless you have object or objectId

Comment: Oh. This is the only way I guess then. To retrieve the object dieat and then delete it. Maybe could movie it to cloud code in the future. Thanks :)